# is there a shorter way to call a function from the sub-namespace in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, namespaces

I'm writing a function inside : `index.fragment.singleEntry`, where I expect to call a function of `index.fragment.singleEntry.editTitle`. Instead of writing the complete namespace of that function, is there a shorter way to call it?

I'm calling:
**`index.fragment.singleEntry.editTitle.load();`**

inside:
**`index.fragment.singleEntry.load`**

Thanks in advance.

```
jQuery.namespace("index.fragment.singleEntry");

index.fragment.singleEntry.load=function(vasId) {
//==================================================
// init GUI components
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "simple",
    width: "500",
    height: "300"
    //elements : "editContentTa"
});
initEditControl(vasId);

index.fragment.singleEntry.editTitle.load();
updateGUI_content();

//===================================================
```

Comment: This is why we avoid namespaces like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
index.fragment.singleEntry.load= (function(singleEntry) {

return function(vasId) {
//==================================================
// init GUI components
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "simple",
    width: "500",
    height: "300"
    //elements : "editContentTa"
});
initEditControl(vasId);

singleEntry.editTitle.load();
updateGUI_content();

...

})(index.fragment.singleEntry)
```

Wrap your code in a closure to make certain variables local. Then return your function.

Alternatively you can call `this.editTable.load()` since `this` in `singleEntry.load` is `singleEntry`

Comment: wow! this is AWESOME! Just look at those embracing paralesis... How did you guys figure it out!